# Geodjango + PostGIS. Aggregate polygon area in square meters

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

I am using geodjango(3.1) + postgis and I want to receive the area of a polygon in square meteres. Therefore, I am using the [Geographic Database Functions of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Area).

My code looks the following:

`City.objects.annotate(area=Area('geom'))`

I think the result I am reciving is in degree. When I use the [distance function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance) the same way, I get the right result in square meters.

When I am executing `ST_Area(geom, use_spheroid=true)` as RawSQL, the result also fits and is in square meteres but I would like the avoid RawSQL.

Thanks for any help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
City.objects.annotate(area=RawSQL("ST_AREA(geom, true)", []))
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you [store your `geom` field as a geography type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geography-type), the `Area` function should return square meters instead of degrees.

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models

class City(gis_models.Model):
    geom = gis_models.PolygonField(geography=True)

…
cities = City.objects.annotate(area=Area('geom'))
cities[0].area.sq_m  # square meters
```